# Spring Data JPA Unable to locate Attribute with the given name

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I was trying to use `Spring Data JPA` on `Spring Boot` and I  kept getting error, I can't figure out what the problem is:

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [firstName] on
>   this ManagedType [com.example.h2demo.domain.Subscriber]

FirstName is declared in my entity class. I have used a service class with DAO before with different project and worked perfectly.

My Entity class (getters and setters are also in the class) :

```
        @Entity
        public class Subscriber {

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String FirstName,LastName,Email;

        public Subscriber(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.Email = email;
          }
        }
...
```

My Repository Class

```
@Component
public interface SubscriberRepository extends JpaRepository<Subscriber,Long> {
    Subscriber findByFirstName(String FirstName);
    Subscriber deleteAllByFirstName(String FirstName);
}
```

My Service Class

```
@Service
public class SubscriberService {

    @Autowired
    private SubscriberRepository subscriberRepository;

    public Subscriber findByFirstName(String name){
        return  subscriberRepository.findByFirstName(name);

    }

    public Subscriber deleteAllByFirstName(String name){
        return  subscriberRepository.deleteAllByFirstName(name);

    }

    public void addSubscriber(Subscriber student) {
        subscriberRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

And My Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/subscribers")
public class SubscriberController {

    @Autowired
    private SubscriberService subscriberService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{name}")
    public Subscriber findByFirstName(@PathVariable("name") String fname){
        return  subscriberService.findByFirstName(fname);
    }

    @PostMapping( value = "/add")
    public String insertStudent(@RequestBody final Subscriber subscriber){
        subscriberService.addSubscriber(subscriber);
        return "Done";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try changing `private String FirstName,LastName,Email;` to `private String firstName,lastName,email;`

It should work.

`findByFirstName` in `SubscriberRepository`  tries to find a field `firstName` by convention which is not there.

Further reference on how properties inside the entities are traversed https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Comment: Can i ask one more question? Sending JSON POST to addSubscriber method gives null values to stored to database. Is there any error in the code??

Comment: try checking the values before calling `addSubscriber`

Comment: In my opinion the accepted answer should suggest the method to identify the problem  in a general way; this answer is only debugging this specific code: soft of pair-programming

Answer (score 15):

The same problem was when i had deal with Spring Data Specifications (https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)

Initial piece of code was:

```
private Specification<Project> checkCriteriaByProjectNumberLike(projectNumber: String) {
    (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("project_number"), "%" + projectNumber)
}
```

The problem was in root.get("project_number"). Inside the method, I had to put the field name as in the model (projectNumber), but I sent the field name as in the database (project_number).

That is, the final correct decision was:

```
private Specification<Project> checkCriteriaByProjectNumberLike(projectNumber: String) {
    (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("projectNumber"), "%" + projectNumber)
}
```

Comment: I was having the same problem until I realized that maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 7):

After I change my `entity class` variables from capital letter to small letter for instance `Username` to `username` the method `Users findByUsername(String username);` is working for me now .

Comment: This saved my day. case of the latters matters

Answer (score 6):

As per [the specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions), the property names should start with lower case.

> [...]The resolution algorithm starts with interpreting the entire part (`AddressZipCode`) as the property and checks the domain class for a property with that name (uncapitalized)[...].

It will try to find a property with uncapitalized name. So use `firstName` instead of `FirstName` and etc..